# Pass data between parent child user controls

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

Let's say I have a *Book app* with the following arrangement:
There are a few page types

- Regular
- With picture
- Only picture
- etc...

Each of this pages can have many bookmarks. In order to display everything correctly I have created a datatemplate selector like this

**Page.xaml**

```
 <Pages:PageTypeSelector Content="{Binding}">
    <Pages:PageTypeSelector.Regular>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">  
                <!-- Show regular content here-->
                <Bookmark:BookmarkView />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pages:PageTypeSelector.Regular>

    <Pages:PageTypeSelector.WithPicture>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">  
                <!-- Show mixed content here-->
                <Bookmark:BookmarkView />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pages:PageTypeSelector.WithPicture>

   <Pages:PageTypeSelector.OnlyPicture>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">  
                <!-- Show picture content here-->
                <Bookmark:BookmarkView />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pages:PageTypeSelector.WithPicture>
 </Pages:PageTypeSelector>
```

How the bookmark view looks like isn't important now (it just displays the bookmarks for each page)

The problem is I need somehow to set it's `PageId` property so that the bookmark control can get the bookmarks from a service.

I have added a property to the `BookmarkView.xmal.cs`

```
public Guid PageId
{
    get { return _pageId; }
    set
    {
        _pageId= value;
        _viewModel.PageId= value; // Here I wanted to pass the same value to the 
                                  // viewModel which would doo the job then
    }
}
```

I have then tried to do something like this

```
<Bookmark:BookmarkView PageId={Binding PageId, Mode=TwoWay}/>
```

Intellisense was suggesting PageId while I was typing but nothing is happening.

How can I pass the PageId to the view?

Edit: Changing to

```
public object PageId
{
    get { return _pageId; }
    set
    {
        _pageId= value;
    }
}
```

Shows me that the `value` is of type `System.Windows.Data.Binding`. How can I now get the value?

Comment: Don't you think PageId property should be a dependency property, to use binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dependency property for PageID.

Comment: Hate this Friday evenings when you forget the easiest thigns. Thanks